# Double faces issue, cant be merged by distance

Tags: modeling, faces, normals

I am working on this game asset and i want to triangulate the mesh. I found double faces on my mesh but merging by distance could not fix the issue. I can delete them by hand an create new face but i hope there is an easier solution.

It might have happened because i used the Bridge tool an also j to create new edges on the mesh, was it a mistake?

[image: double faces]

Comment: Have you tried increasing the merge by distance parameter?

Comment: Yes it didn't help. I now deleted the faces and rebuild them. Is there a function like "Bridge" but with cutting the face not creating new faces on top of them?